# SQL Server service broker related rights issue

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stproc_ssb_send]
  @iname varchar(20)
WITH EXECUTE AS 'xyz'
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @DIALOG_HANDLE UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @MSG varchar(max) 

SET @MSG='<MESSAGE>
        <test>' + @iname + '</test>
        </MESSAGE>'

    BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @DIALOG_HANDLE
    FROM SERVICE START_PROC_PROCESS_SERVICE
    TO SERVICE 'EXECUTE_PROC_PROCESS_SERVICE'
    ON CONTRACT [PROC_PROCESS_CONTRACT]
    WITH ENCRYPTION= OFF;

    SEND ON CONVERSATION @DIALOG_HANDLE
    MESSAGE TYPE PROC_PROCESS_MT(@MSG);

    END CONVERSATION @DIALOG_HANDLE
END
```

error:

> Msg 15517, Level 16, State 1, Procedure [stproc_ssb_send], Line 0
>   Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "xyz" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.

`XYZ` is `db_owner` / `db_ddladmin` for this database.

Procedure is created using `sa`; error occurs while executing.

Comment: GRANT CONTROL ON DATABASE::DatabaseName TO XYZ.. try to execute this first and then check if t works?

Comment: sorry, but no use

Comment: People are editing your question to make it easier to read and to conform to formatting conventions here. Please stop rolling back their efforts.

Comment: Have you granted authorization as `alter authorization on database::[your_DB_NAME] to [sa];` ?

Comment: Is XYZ an AD group?  If so it can't be used for this type of thing. (hence the error).  If not what type of account is it?

Comment: yes grant already given & sa is owner

Answer (score -2, accepted):

ALTER DATABASE  SET trustworthy ON

This query solved my prob. Thanks for efforts.

Comment: I added this answer when externally find. I think many of user on Stack network busy in stupid comments instead of helping others